# Pandas: Get first and last row of the same date and calculate time difference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I have a date and a time column.
Each row describes some event. I want to calculate the timespan for each different day and add it as new row. The actual calculation is not that important (which units etc.), I just want to know, how I can the first and last row for each date, to access the time value.
The dataframe is already sorted by date and all rows of the same date are also ordered by the time.

Minimal example of what I have

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["01.01.2020", "01.01.2020", "01.01.2020", "02.02.2022", "02.02.2022"], 
                   "Time": ["12:00", "13:00", "14:45", "02:00", "08:00"]})
df
```

[image]

and what I want

[image]

EDIT: The duration column should be calculated by
14:45 - 12:00 = 2:45 for the first date and
08:00 - 02:00 = 6:00 for the second date.

I suspect this is possible with the groupby function but I am not sure how exactly to do it.

Comment: did the answer worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you will find this helpful.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["01.01.2020", "01.01.2020", "01.01.2020", "02.02.2022", "02.02.2022"],
                   "Time": ["12:00", "13:00", "14:45", "02:00", "08:00"]})

df["Datetime"] = pd.to_datetime((df["Date"] + " " + df["Time"]))


def date_diff(df):
    df["Duration"] = df["Datetime"].max() - df["Datetime"].min()
    return df


df = df.groupby("Date").apply(date_diff)

df = df.drop("Datetime", axis=1)
```

Output:

```
         Date   Time        Duration
0  01.01.2020  12:00 0 days 02:45:00
1  01.01.2020  13:00 0 days 02:45:00
2  01.01.2020  14:45 0 days 02:45:00
3  02.02.2022  02:00 0 days 06:00:00
4  02.02.2022  08:00 0 days 06:00:00
```

You can then do some string styling:

```
df['Duration'] = df['Duration'].astype(str).map(lambda x: x[7:12])
```

Output:

```
         Date   Time Duration
0  01.01.2020  12:00    02:45
1  01.01.2020  13:00    02:45
2  01.01.2020  14:45    02:45
3  02.02.2022  02:00    06:00
4  02.02.2022  08:00    06:00
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it

```
# groupby on Date and find the difference of max and min time in each group
# format it as HH:MM by extracting Hours and minutes
# and creating a dictionary
d=dict((df.groupby('Date')['Time'].apply(lambda x: 
                                  (pd.to_timedelta(x.max() +':00')  - 
                                   pd.to_timedelta(x.min() +':00') 
                                  )
                                 ).astype(str).str.extract(r'days (..:..)')
).reset_index().values)


# map the dictionary and update the duration in DF
df['duration']=df['Date'].map(d)
df
```

```
    Date    Time    duration
0   01.01.2020  12:00   02:45
1   01.01.2020  13:00   02:45
2   01.01.2020  14:45   02:45
3   02.02.2022  02:00   06:00
4   02.02.2022  08:00   06:00
```

Answer (score 0):

By the example shown below, you can achieve want you want.

```
df['Start time'] = df.apply(lambda row: df[df['Date'] == row['Date']]['Time'].max(), axis=1)
df
```

Update:

```
import datetime
df['Duration'] = df.apply(lambda row: str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=(datetime.datetime.strptime(df[df['Date'] == row['Date']]['Time'].max(), '%H:%M') - datetime.datetime.strptime(df[df['Date'] == row['Date']]['Time'].min(), '%H:%M')).total_seconds())) , axis=1)
df
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. While this is already helpful, this is not quite I want. Maybe I was not quite clear. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: `df['Duration'] = df.apply(lambda row: str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=(datetime.datetime.strptime(df[df['Date'] == row['Date']]['Time'].max(), '%H:%M') - datetime.datetime.strptime(df[df['Date'] == row['Date']]['Time'].min(), '%H:%M')).total_seconds()))[:-3] , axis=1)` gives you exactly what you want

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import numpy as np 

df['xdate']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' '+ df['Time'],format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')

df['max']=df.groupby(df['xdate'].dt.date)['xdate'].transform(np.max) #get max dates each date
df['min']=df.groupby(df['xdate'].dt.date)['xdate'].transform(np.min) #get min date each date

#get difference max and min dates
df['Duration']= df[['min','max']].apply(lambda x: x['max'] - timedelta(hours=x['min'].hour,minutes=x['min'].minute,seconds=x['min'].second),axis=1).dt.strftime('%H:%M') 

df=df.drop(['xdate','min','max'],axis=1)

print(df)
'''
         Date   Time Duration
0  01.01.2020  12:00    02:45
1  01.01.2020  13:00    02:45
2  01.01.2020  14:45    02:45
3  02.02.2022  02:00    06:00
4  02.02.2022  08:00    06:00
'''
```